# Entityframework core 7 with Oracle database in .Net 6 application

Tags: oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, odac

Can I use entityframework core 7 with oracle database for an exiting tables and views?
I just want to add the tables and views to the context and will not add migration or change anything through the .net 6 application.

Comment: EF Core 7 is not released yet. Also Oracle provider is not updated to EF Core 7. Check [versions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/#versions-body-tab). Answer is: wait for official support.

Comment: Yes, exactly.
I used EF core 6 as i couldn't wait for Oracle provide official release for EF core 7.

Comment: I do not see solution here. Oracle provider for some unknown reason is closed source.

Comment: You can create issue [here](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues) and ask when they plan to release preview version,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must Scaffold database like this command
Scaffold-DbContext "DATA SOURCE=Datasource;PASSWORD=xxxxxx;USER ID=xxxxx" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -Tables PURCHASEORDER -Force  -Context "AppDBContext"

Comment: Yes this is what i did but  i used EF core 6 not 7.